# How to use boolean AND and NOT operators in Gmail search

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters, search-operators

I'm trying to find mails that have one address in the recipients but another not in it.

I'm trying things like `from:address1@gmail.com and not from:address2@gmail.com` and `from:(address1@gmail.com and not address2@gmail.com)`

None of them work, and I can't find a good help page about boolean operators either.

Anyone has any idea?

Comment: Actually, your search doesn’t make much sense—you can’t receive an email from more than one recipient, so `form: someone but-not-from: someone else` can’t really work. You are probably trying to search for emails that were sent only to a restricted group of recipients.

Comment: I couldn't find an exact answer for this but what worked for me was using double quotes to cause the AND operator functionality. So with reference to OP's `from:"address1@gmail.com" NOT from:address2@gmail.com` should behave like AND

Answer (score 131, accepted):

> The 'or' function in Gmail is represented by 'OR'. You also can use quotes (" ") to specify an exact phrase.

From the [Gmail help page on Boolean operators](http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=8931).

The 'not' function is represented by a minus (-), like `-from:(...)`, `-{from:(...)}`, or `-(from:(...))`

Comment: And the AND operator? Does just adding 2 restrictions make it an AND by default?

Comment: AND is the default.

Comment: I have the feeling that the default is OR, because I got results from both words not together

Comment: The robustness is pretty awesome actually, and you can negate whole subexpressions; I frequently search unread email *not* from a list of senders: `is:unread -{ from:a from:b ... }`

Comment: Note that you need to use double quotes `"` when specifying exact phrases. I got weird results using single quotes `'`.

Comment: Here is an example `from:address1@company1.com -address2@company1.com`

Answer (score 32):

Use the minus sign to make a negative rule.  You can also string rules together by just leaving a space between separate rules.

For example:

```
from:name@company.com -from:name2@company.com
```

or you can do things like

```
is:unread -in:spam -in:trash
```

Answer (score 9):

For *not* in Google, use `-`, like so:

```
from:addres1@gmail.com -address2@gmail.com
```

Comment: from:-address@example.com doesn't seem to work for me when there are multiple messages in the same "conversation". Since SOME of those messages were NOT from address@example.com, it consider it a match and moves the ENTIRE conversation, even though one of the messages WAS from address@example.com so I would like the entire conversation to stay in the inbox... It's really tricky when Gmail tries to group things into conversations based on message similarity of subject/body! I wish the REPLIES to these messages could show up in my inbox even though the ORIGINALS got archived...

Comment: @TylerRick I have the exact same problem than the one you described here. Any idea since 2012? ;)

Answer (score 8):

when trying to avoid multiple phrases in a subject line for selection:

```
-("phrase one" OR "phrase two" OR "word1")
```

Comment: This is the best answer. You can combine with brackets like this: -from:(gmail.com OR google.com) This will filter all emails from anybody at gmail.com or google.com

Comment: Is this equivalent to `-{"phrase one" "phrase two" "word1"}`?

Comment: @MarcelWilson it is not the same, having the OR in between the words is required logic.

Comment: I'm confused then.  My understanding of the curly braces is all items contained within are OR'ed.  While the parenthesis is a grouping, which if all items are OR'ed would mean they would be equivalent?  Am I being dense?

Comment: @MarcelWilson I spoke too soon - you are correct, I wasn't paying attention to the curly braces. According to the documentation curly braces replace the need for OR inside of parentheses.

Answer (score 6):

This will work:

```
from:@company1.com -address2@company1.com
```

This puts all messages from any sender at `company1.com` into a folder except those from the individual `address2@compay1.com`.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for and works great! I'm not sure why someone downvoted you.