# Prevent label from being applied

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters, gmail-labels

How can I prevent Gmail from applying certain labels to messages.

For example, I have a "Work" label and a "Home" label. Gmail is labeling some messages as both "Work" and "Home."  How do I prevent this?

I have a filter that specifies "Work" when it comes to my work email address.
I have a filter that specifies "Home" when it comes to my personal email address.

How do I tell Gmail not to apply both labels to an email coming to one but not the other?

My filters are as follows:

Matches: `to:(myname@myworkaddress.com)`
Do this: `Apply label "Work", Never send it to Spam`

Matches: `to:(mymickname@homesweethome.com)`
Do this: `Apply label "Home", Never send it to Spam`

Also, as a note, I never receive emails sent to both my home and work email addresses.

Comment: It would be great if you could explicitly include the filters you use with some dummy email addresses so that we can have a concrete example.

Comment: I added the filters I use to my question above.

Comment: Thanks for adding the particular filters you're using, that helps with debugging! In order to find out what's going on, we have to investigate a bit further. Could you add the two following details to the question: 1. Run a search with ``to:(myname@myworkaddress.com) to:(mymickname@homesweethome.com)`` and see whether it returns anything. I suspect you will get results, have a look at a few emails and tell us who the emails were addressed to. 2. Find a few emails that have both "Work" and "Home" labels applied and see who they were sent to. Without this information I can't do more.

Comment: I ran that search and received no results. All work emails are getting both my home and work label. (None of my home emails are getting labeled as work)

Answer (score 1):

I assume you create labels using a filter like "to:a@a.com". Your problem are presumably emails that are sent to *both* of your email addresses.

In order to avoid an email being labelled by both you can simple create a new filter set A', B' using a negation operator on one of the two:

```
A'="to:a@a.com"
B'="to:b@b.com" -"to:a@a.com"
```

So now messages that have the label A=A' applied will no longer have label B' applied. You can also refine your filter A' to exclude a few intersection matches.

On operators for Gmail filters read: [How to use boolean AND and NOT operators in Gmail search](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/31411/how-to-use-boolean-and-and-not-operators-in-gmail-search)